# NodeJS: HTML page doesn't read the script path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I created a web server with NodeJs that loads upon it an HTML page with a script inside. If I open the HTML page in the same directory as the script.js the script obviously works. If I open it in the web server the HTML page doesn't find the script and therefore does not work. I tried to change the path of the file but it say "Cannot risolve directory..." How can I do? Thank you.

**This is the code that starts the web-server and upload the html page inside:**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/home/Test.html', function (err, html) {

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
});
```

**This is the script.js file:**

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{

    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "Test.txt";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";


    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

**This is the HTML file:**

```
<html><head><title>Test</title><script type="text/javascript" src="/home/Script.js"></script>
</head><body>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:640px">

Text....

</textarea> <br>
<br><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Download</button>
```

***Also writing the full path to the script in the HTML file, the page does not find it, how can I do?***

Comment: `express.static` is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the js, because the js file is not on the web server. Before you reference the js, ensure it is on the server and you can load it from the server, like this: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/home/Script.js'. All of our static files, such as img, css, js should be put on server, so we can use them.

Here is my code:
**app.js:**

```
var http = require("http"),
url  = require("url"),
path = require("path"),
fs   = require("fs");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var pathname=__dirname+url.parse(req.url).pathname;
if (path.extname(pathname)=="") {
    pathname+="/";
}
if (pathname.charAt(pathname.length-1)=="/"){
    pathname+="home/Test.html";
}
fs.exists(pathname,function(exists){
    if(exists){
        switch(path.extname(pathname)){
            case ".html":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                break;
            case ".js":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
                break;
            case ".css":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
                break;
            case ".gif":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/gif"});
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"});
                break;
            case ".png":
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
                break;
            default:
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"});
        }
        fs.readFile(pathname,function (err,data){
            res.end(data);
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end("<h1>404 Not Found</h1>");
    }
 });
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/");
```

**Test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="home/Script.js"></script>
</head><body>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:640px">
111
Text....
</textarea>
<br>
<br><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With your code i get error 404 not found. Obviously the directory is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) - To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname + '/to/home/folder'));
```

then you able to use t he files inside the **/to/home/folder**
via **/home/file.ext**

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***

The script is in "/home/Script"

This is my **app.js** now, **but the HTML page still not reading the script.**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

fs.readFile('/home/test.html', function (err, html) {

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write(html);
        res.end();

        app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname + '/Script'));

    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse your code

```
app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname+'/script'));
```

The `/home` is the statement is actually a virtual directory, not exactly the folder name. You can use any word instead of 'home'. Now the  `__dirname` here specify the current physical folder in which this app.js file resides. It is a built-in keyword.
Since both your script.js and HTML and app.js files reside in the same folder you don't need to append anything to the __dirname.

So you should modify the above code statement to this

```
app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname));
```

And your script tag should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Since you use express, you can simply write this to serve your page instead of writing lengthy native code

```
    app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname));
    app.get('/home',function(req,res,next){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/test.html');
    });
    app.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1',function(){
        console.log("server is listening to the port 1337");
    });
```